# A web service returning a date with slashes causes Java Axis2 client to fail

Tags: java, apache-axis, adb

There's a lot of talk of Axis2 date format issues, but I can't find anything about this particular problem.

I have a partner's WSDL, on which I have run Axis2's wsdl2java tool to create the Java code. I did not specify a -d option, so I believe the data binding will be the default - ADB.

I am calling a method on the service and it returns XML that contains a date in this format:

```
<ns1:thedate>2012/12/10 07:45:08.000 -0800</ns1:thedate>
```

and getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid date format (2012/12/10 07:45:08.000 -0800) with out - s at correct place 
at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToDateTime(ConverterUtil.java:896)
```

The slashes are the problem. Creating my own converter class is not an option because the methods of org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil are static and therefore cannot be overridden. Sure I can set `adb.converterutil` system property to my class, but ConverterUtil does not check `isCustomClassPresent` in the convertToDateTime method.

I'm not really sure what my options are. Any helpful ideas?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Can you use a string and convert it after you've gotten it into your object?  Or is it typed already in the xml namespace?

Comment: @unicorn Hi. It's already typed. The WSDL says it is xsd:date. I'm thinking of changin the WSDL to xsd:string and regenerating the code. I can't see another option.

Comment: Yeah, if you can modify the wsdl then that is probably your easiest option, although you will have to remember that you changed it next time the wsdl itself is republished.  Next time it is republished, though, you can discuss with the person responsible.